# In Rails, is there an easy way to check out the attributes of an ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm aware that I can check an ActiveRecord through the rails console but it shows the entire output in one line.  This can be an issue to look up a specific attribute if the table has many columns.

```
>> Story
=> Story(id: integer, name: string, link: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

I like how the attributes are displayed in the create migration files but if I have many migration files, it might be a bit hard to track the one that I want.

In Django, I can go straight to the models.py and check the attributes for any models I want.  How do Rails developers do this kind of lookup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`config/schema.rb` has the db schema, and in other words all the attributes. I just open the file and search for "posts" for a Post model, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to use the annotate_models plugin/gem. It will add a comment to the top of your model files.

An example (from the README):

```
  Schema as of Sun Feb 26 21:58:32 CST 2006 (schema version 7)
  #
  #  id                  :integer(11)   not null
  #  quantity            :integer(11)   
  #  product_id          :integer(11)   
  #  unit_price          :float         
  #  order_id            :integer(11)   
  #
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally just describe the table from the database shell.

Answer (score 0):

From the rails console (`rails/console` from the project root)

```
Story.columns_hash.each {|k,v| puts "#{k} => #{v.type}"}
```

which will output:

```
id => integer
name => string
link => string
...
etc
```